# Netgear A6210 - Wifi stops working when computer is restarted

Tags: 16.04, wireless, adapter, netgear

I was having issues installing the drivers for the Netgear A6210 wifi adapter, but then I found this and it worked!

```
git clone -b port-to-4.15 https://github.com/kaduke/Netgear-A6210.git
cd Netgear-A6210
make
sudo make install
```

However, now I'm noticing that every time I restart my computer the wifi stops working and I have to uninstall and reinstall. After I reinstall it starts working again, but it's frustrating having to do that every time I need to restart my computer... Has anyone else seen this issue and found a fix? Thanks!

Comment: Do you only reboot after kernel updates?

Comment: No, I rebooted after installing video editing software. Since then I've restarted my computer a couple times to try different fixes, but the wifi still stops working after every restart